Drools Speadsheet syntax to generate OOPATH format drl file
Is it possible to generate drl file in OOPATH format from a spreadsheet?
Is there a flag to switch?
I don't find any examples.
This spreadsheet

generates a traditional syntax drl:
package com....;
unit OrderUnit;

import com....OrderRequest;

rule "LOYAL_cusomer_v001"
    when
        OrderRequest(customerType.getValue1 == "LOYAL")
    then
        orderDiscount.setDiscount(orderDiscount.getDiscount() + 5);
end

When I ran unitInstance.fire(), the rule is not recognized.
It works when I modify the drl as following and test against this file directly :
    when
        /orderRequest[ customerType.getValue1 == "LOYAL" ]


Here is an example that works:
Speadsheet:

it generates the following drl file:
package com.abcdef.ruleunit.order;
unit OrderUnit;
//generated from Decision Table
import com.abcdef.model.order.OrderRequest;
import com.abcdef.model.order.CustomerType;
import com.abcdef.model.order.OrderDiscount;
query getDiscount $orderRequest: /orderRequest[$customerNumber: customerNumber, $age: age, $amount: amount, $customerType: customerType.getValue ] end
// rule values at A11, header at A6
rule "LOYAL_cusomer_v001"
    when
        $orderRequest: /orderRequest[customerType.getValue == "LOYAL"]
    then
        orderDiscount.setDiscount(orderDiscount.getDiscount() + 5);
end

// rule values at A12, header at A6
rule "New_or_Dissatisfied_customer_v001"
    when
        $orderRequest: /orderRequest[customerType.getValue != "LOYAL"]
    then
        orderDiscount.setDiscount(orderDiscount.getDiscount() + 3);
end

// rule values at A13, header at A6
rule "Customer_order_amount_v001"
    when
        $orderRequest: /orderRequest[amount == 10000]
    then
        orderDiscount.setDiscount(orderDiscount.getDiscount() + 5);
end

// rule values at A14, header at A6
rule "Customer_age_v001"
    when
        $orderRequest: /orderRequest[age < 20 || age > 50]
    then
        orderDiscount.setDiscount(orderDiscount.getDiscount() + 10);
end


drl.csv is not supported. Only drl.xls and drl.xlsx files in the same package are loaded.

Apache POI is used to load Excel file, POI-HSSF supports Excel '97(-2007) file format. PON-XSSF/SXSSF supports Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx).
